# How to get the all the recyclerView Items into ArrayList using appium

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have a scenario to verify the Sort&Filter functionality for Mobile App in Android.

Scenario:

1. Search for Item
2. Search Result Apper
3. Sort&Filter with some criteria
4. Have to Verify that Sort&Filter is applied correctly

Here results are added to RecyclerView.
As per RecyclerView/appium functionality, all the items are not loaded into view. Only visible Items are loaded into the view Hierarchy.
When I scroll Up the Linear Layout Indexes are re-arranged. I could not able to get all the Items.

Could you kindly provide me any sample scenario of this kind?

Or How can we achieve this kind of scenarios in Real Automation while working on the project?
[image]

Regards,
Shiva Oleti

Answer (score 0):

Issue with Android as You stated is that it "sees" only what is visible on screen. I have similar issue, so I had to go deeper into element and fetch text. In your case I would do following:

*1. Search Result Appear:*
- fetch all visible elements, input search, fetch again -n results containing search result. Eg. if input 'beer' there should be eg. 4 elements with text containing "beer". Put elements in list and iterate:

```
List <MobileElement> listElements = driver.findElements(By.id("someId"));

for(MobileElement el : listElements){
   if(el.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(expected)){
       // do some validation //
   }
}
```

2. Search Result Appear:

   - input exact value that will return unique, one result so You can easily count.
3. Sort&Filter with some criteria

   - remember initial values in items (text like 'Budweiser beer'), do some filtering / sorting, and check text in first element if is changed and if correct logic is applied (eg. sort desc.)
4. Have to Verify that Sort&Filter is applied correctly

   - think I answered in **3.**

Basically:

1. 'pick' text from items store them,
2. do some action (search, sort, filter),
3. 'pick' newly changed items caused by 2. step, store them,
4. compare (depending on what You need...),

To get all items you have to swipe and store them in list.

Comment: Kindly provide any working piece of code. I think i am not understanding your solution